# yum search - package version

Tags: yum, search

How can I tell the version of a package after doing a yum search?

e.g.

```
yum search rabbitmq
```

returns

```
rabbitmq-server.noarch : The RabbitMQ server
```

I need to know the version of this server.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can find the version number of a package in your repositories with the `yum info` command.

```
# yum info rabbitmq-server
Available Packages
Name        : rabbitmq-server
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 2.6.1
Release     : 1.fc16
Size        : 1.1 M
Repo        : updates
Committer   : Peter Lemenkov <lemenkov@gmail.com>
Committime  : Tue Nov  8 13:00:00 2011
Buildtime   : Tue Nov  8 10:31:03 2011
Summary     : The RabbitMQ server
URL         : http://www.rabbitmq.com/
License     : MPLv1.1
Description : RabbitMQ is an implementation of AMQP, the emerging standard for high
            : performance enterprise messaging. The RabbitMQ server is a robust and
            : scalable implementation of an AMQP broker.
```

To find the version numbers of installed packages, you can use `rpm` with the `-q` option.

```
# rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64
kernel-3.3.2-1.fc16.x86_64
kernel-3.3.2-6.fc16.x86_64
```

Comment: my version is much older...which repo are you using?

Comment: I ran this command on my Fedora 16 laptop, but the command applies to any system with yum and rpm, such as RHEL or CentOS.

Comment: I'm running Centos 6 but my repo looks old...is there a way to update it?

Comment: The EPEL repositories (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) also offer RabbitMQ-server 2.6.1 in their repository for CentOS/RHEL 6. Here's a guide to get you going: http://johnpoelstra.com/2010/12/23/rhel-6-epel/

Answer (score 13):

AFAIK, `yum info` only shows information for one specific "instance" of a package. I wanted to know not what version I had installed but which were available on the repos. So this did it for me:

```
yum -v list package_name --show-duplicates
```

Comment: `yum info` shows all packages, installed and available in enabled repos, by the name specified.  Or if you run it without a package name it'll just show you all the info that it has.

Comment: --show-duplicates  (with dash)

Comment: @Xalorous What version?  I only get the current package with `yum info` (on a system apparently old enough that `--show-duplicates` isn't an option to `yum list`)

Comment: RHEL 6.9, yum 3.2.29.  And I'm seeing the same behavior you are.  It only lists the installed versions.  Possibly latest version if it is newer than installed.  E.g. I see 3 kernels, 2.6.32, all installed.  But I know our (custom) repo has a bunch more.

Comment: Note: --showduplicates (without dash) here on CentOS 8 (dnf/v4.2.23)

Answer (score 3):

You can get more info with the following command:

```
yum info rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 3):

OR

```
yum list rabbitmq
```

if you prefer condensed output.